# Find response of discrete time LTI system given input and impulse response

Tags: discrete-signals, fourier-transform, homework

[image: Full question]

For this question the guide says to use $Y(e^{j\omega}) = H(e^{j\omega}) X(e^{j\omega})$.
I have been able to find the discrete time Fourier transform of the impulse function as $$H(e^{j\omega}) = \frac{1}{1-\frac12 e^{-j\omega}}$$
Finding the same for the impulse function is what I do not understand.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the $n$ in the denominator of the definition of $x[n]$ is a typo or misinterpretation. I guess it's meant to be a $4$ or something similar. Whatever it is, the term in parentheses is very likely supposed to be a constant.

Comment: You're right, the lecturer for the course commented after the submission that the denominator n was supposed to be 4.

Comment: 1: are you sure you're supposed to use the Fourier transform here?  2: What is the definition of $\delta[n]$ (i.e., the impulse)?  What happens if you just plug that into the definition of the Fourier transform (or whatever tool you ought to be using)?

Answer (score 0):

Note that the given definition of $x[n]$ is undefined for $n=0$. But even if you changed it by replacing the unit step $u[n]$ by the shifted step $u[n-1]$ to exclude the value $n=0$, then the problem would still be very hard to solve. So it's more than likely that the correct definition of $x[n]$ has no $n$ in the denominator, and the current form is just a consequence of a typo or of a misinterpretation.